# libc++abi.dylib: Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I went back and re-wrote my code and made sure the parameters were all in the right place.  But now, when I run my app in iOS Simulator, I get a Thread 1:signal SIGABRT error and the following error in my Debug area:

```
2014-11-04 00:39:12.288 Juxta[60526:1144351] +[_TtCFC5Juxta14ViewController11viewDidLoadFS0_FT_T_L_7Counter parseClassName]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1059bb640
2014-11-04 00:39:12.291 Juxta[60526:1144351] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[_TtCFC5Juxta14ViewController11viewDidLoadFS0_FT_T_L_7Counter parseClassName]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1059bb640'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c183f5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108746bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c1f40d +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106b777fc ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106b77398 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Juxta                               0x00000001057e2812 -[PFObject(Private) init] + 143
    6   Juxta                               0x00000001057d59f0 _TFCFC5Juxta14ViewController11viewDidLoadFS0_FT_T_L_7CountercfMS1_FT_S1_ + 64
    7   Juxta                               0x00000001057d5a32 _TFCFC5Juxta14ViewController11viewDidLoadFS0_FT_T_L_7CounterCfMS1_FT_S1_ + 50
    8   Juxta                               0x00000001057d44a7 _TFC5Juxta14ViewController11viewDidLoadfS0_FT_T_ + 1575
    9   Juxta                               0x00000001057d47f2 _TToFC5Juxta14ViewController11viewDidLoadfS0_FT_T_ + 34
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001075c7190 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 738
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001075c738e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001074e6db9 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 58
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001074e7152 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 276
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001074f365c -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010749e191 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2628
    16  UIKit                               0x00000001074a0e5c -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1350
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010749fd22 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010c3472a3 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106b4dabc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106b43805 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106b435c5 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106b42a06 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010749f799 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    24  UIKit                               0x00000001074a2550 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    25  Juxta                               0x00000001057d6e7e top_level_code + 78
    26  Juxta                               0x00000001057d6eba main + 42
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001097a8145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Here's my code just so it's more clear:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var testObject = PFObject(className: "TestObject")
    testObject["foo"] = "bar"
    testObject.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)

    class Counter : PFObject {
        var voteCount: Int = 0
        func incrementBy(amount: Int, numberOfTimes times: Int) { voteCount += amount * times
            println(" \(voteCount) votes")
        }
    }

    var countOption1 = PFObject(className: "countOption1")
        countOption1 = Counter()
        countOption1.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(PFObject.self, selector: nil)

}





override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Any hint as to what could be wrong with my code? I was very careful this time.

Comment: Learn how to properly format your code.

Comment: I just formatted it correctly but now I'm getting a totally new error, as I've edited above.

Comment: Do you understand what "unrecognized selector" means?  It means that you have caused the `parseClassName` method to be "sent" to a class that does not recognize it.  It's a little hard (ok, *a lot* hard) to read the screwy Swift stack trace, but probably in Juxta14ViewController you are creating a PFObject and passing it the wrong parameter (an instance of your Counter class, I think).

Comment: (Unless Swift is even screwier that I think, you appear to do a double-assign of `countOption1`.  I suspect that `countOption1 = Counter()` is bogus.)

Comment: (If your comprehension of programming principles is at this level you really should not be programming in Swift.  Objective-C is not a beginner's language, and Swift is even worse, since it's poorly documented and buggy.  Please consider switching to Java/Android.)

Comment: Well you're right, the countOption = Counter() is the only line that's causing the issue.  When I remove that line the app runs without any problems. However, I still need to execute that function in the Counter class, which is adding one vote every time a button is pressed and saving it to my Parse database (hence the PFObject). Do you know if there's an alternative to execute that function?

Answer (score 0):

You must have made some copy and paste mistake. There is no reason, for example, that:

- `class Counter` is defined inside a UIViewController
- `class Counter` has a `didReceiveMemoryWarning` function
- Another `class Counter` in `countOption1` function.

It is a mess

Comment: I just re-formatted it but I'm getting an uncaught exception error, what could be the issue now?